# how to generate class instances of attributes on demand?

Tags: java, dozer

I'm evaluating the dozer framework right. I was wondering whether it is possible to handle the following use case:

the classes:

```
public ClassA {

   private Set<ItemA> aItems;
}

public ClassB {

   private ClassC cInstance;
}

public ClassC {

   private List<ItemB> bItems;
}
```

the dozer mapping:

```
<mapping>
   <class-a>ClassA</class-a>
   <class-b>ClassB</class-b>
   <field>
      <a>aItems</a>
      <b>cInstance.bItems</b>
   </field>
 </mapping>
```

From my testings so far, this doesn't seem to work. I was especially wondering how should I tell dozer that it should generate an instance of ClassB **and** ClassC on demand? Especially do I need a specific dozer mapping for ClassB, which only exists as "intermediate" class in my destination model?

PS: If it helps, my destination model consists of JAXB classes

PPS: I also tried to modify the setter method for cInstance that if it is null it should generate a new instance of ClassC - unfortunately, without any luck. Furthermore, I do not want to modify the setter method in that way (however, maybe I can outsource this to a Factory class that will be utilised for the mapping)

Comment: Wow, not sure what you are trying to do here. It seems like you are trying to use Dozer as an object factory, rather than as a copy tool.

Comment: Have you modified the setter for cInstance, or the getter? You wrote the former but it should be the latter. [Deep mapping](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/deepmapping.html) sounds like what you want, but also like what you tried, so I don't know how that failed. A [create method](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customCreateMethod.html) might help to create instances of `ClassB` where the `cInstance` field is already initialized, if that is acceptable.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment @MvG. Yeah, you are probably right, I modified the setter and not the getter (so I'll try it the other way around). You are also right that I'm trying to do a deeper mapping. I'll try the workaround with a specific create method (albeit, I initially not intended to modify the generated JAXB classes of the destination model).

Comment: just as a short note: I got it to work somehow, however, not really ideal, i.e., I'm utilising right now direct access ('is-accessible="true"') and did some modifications at the JAXB classes (but this wasn't my initial intention). So I'll try to find a solution with a customized bean factory and probably direct access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like that the final solution is rather simple, since my destination classes are JAXB classes, I could simply utilise the default factory for JAXB classes (org.dozer.factory.JAXBBeanFactory). The tipping point probably is that the deep mapping destination field should be accessed directly ('is-accessible="true"'). However, I also created a further direct mapping from ClassA.aitems to ClassC.cItems (but I'm not 100% sure whether this will be utilised for the described ClassA to ClassB mapping).
Anyway, finally I found a rather simple and intuitive solution with less/no additional factory coding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Dozer, but judging from the manual, the following should work: Create a [custom bean factory](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/custombeanfactories.html) for `ClassB` implementing the [dozer `BeanFactory` interface](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/dozer/BeanFactory.html):

```
public class FactoryB implements BeanFactory {
  public Object createBean(Object source, Class sourceClass,
                           String targetBeanId) {
    assert(sourceClass.equals(ClassA.class));
    assert(ClassB.class.getName().equals(targetBeanId));
    ClassA a = (ClassA)source;
    ClassB b = new ClassB();
    if (a.aItems != null && !a.aItems.isEmpty())
      b.cInstance = new ClassC();
    return b;
  }
}
```

If your fields are really private, and you don't have public accessors for them, you might have to circumvent access restrictions, but for JAXB-generated classes this should not be the case.

Now you should be able to map things with a [deep mapping](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/deepmapping.html) like this:

```xml
<mapping>
   <class-a>ClassA</class-a>
   <class-b bean-factory="FactoryB">ClassB</class-b>
   <field>
      <a>aItems</a>
      <b>cInstance.bItems</b>
   </field>
 </mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @MvG. So far as I understand the dozer manual, I have to define org.dozer.factory.JAXBBeanFactory as bean factory and then it will load the related ObjectFactory of the JAXB classes that was generated XJC. However, maybe I need to create and define another factory that is related to the requirements of dozer.

Comment: @zazi: The JAXB factory will create objects all right, but it will fail to create that initial cInstance if and only if it is required. Unless the schema already defines that the object will be there if and only if its bItems are not empty. In any case, you can replace the `new ClassB()` and the `new ClassC()` in my code with a call to the JAXB factory, although I would expect that factory to do the same thing.

Comment: I tried your suggestion (also in combination with create-method) at the destination field, however without any luck. it still throws a NPE and can't really see why.

Comment: see my comment to the question. I found a workable but not ideal solution for now.